# Selecting and grouping with subqueries in MySQL - Returning latest record

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm new here, someone would have a possible solution to a problem I could not solve with subquery, any idea how to solve the problem?

Basically I need all patients "pa_name", most current exam for each "field: pe_d2" Like "Expected Result:"

I tried to make a sketch of the result, might help understand the problem ...

The "pacient_exams" table has very many records, the query needs to be very fast.

Thanks in advance for possible solutions! []

```
patient_exams                                    
+-------+----------+----------+------------+------------+  
| pe_id | pe_pa_id | pe_ex_id |    pe_d1   |    pe_d2   |  
+-------+----------+----------+------------+------------+  
|   1   |     1    |     1    | 2014-05-19 | 2016-05-19 |
|   2   |     1    |     2    | 2014-05-19 | 2015-05-19 |
|   3   |     1    |     3    | 2014-05-26 | 2014-11-26 |
|   4   |     1    |     3    | 2014-05-19 | 2014-11-19 |
|   5   |     1    |     4    | 2013-05-19 | 2013-11-19 |
|   6   |     1    |     4    | 2014-05-19 | 2014-11-19 |
|   7   |     3    |     1    | 2013-08-19 | 2014-08-19 |
|   8   |     3    |     1    | 2014-05-01 | 2017-05-01 |
|   9   |     4    |     2    | 2013-05-02 | 2014-05-02 |
|   10  |     4    |     2    | 2013-11-01 | 2014-05-01 |
|   11  |     4    |     4    | 2013-05-02 | 2014-05-02 |
|   12  |     4    |     4    | 2013-11-01 | 2014-05-01 |
+-------+----------+----------+------------+------------+  

patient              exams 
+-------+---------+  +-------+---------+    
| pa_id | pa_name |  | ex_id | ex_name |
+-------+---------+  +-------+---------+    
|   1   | John M. |  |   1   |  Exam 1 | 
|   2   | Slater  |  |   2   |  Exam 2 | 
|   3   | Jonny   |  |   3   |  Exam 3 | 
|   4   | Jessy   |  |   4   |  Exam 4 | 
|  ...  | ...     |  |  ...  |  ...    |
+-------+---------+  +-------+---------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+-------+---------+---------+------------+------------+  
| pe_id | pa_name | ex_name |    pe_d1   |    pe_d2   |  
+-------+---------+---------+------------+------------+
|   9   | Jessy   | Exam 2  | 2013-05-02 | 2014-05-02 |
|   11  | Jessy   | Exam 4  | 2013-05-02 | 2014-05-02 |
|   1   | John M. | Exam 1  | 2014-05-19 | 2016-05-19 |
|   2   | John M. | Exam 2  | 2014-05-19 | 2015-05-19 |
|   3   | John M. | Exam 3  | 2014-05-26 | 2014-11-26 |
|   6   | John M. | Exam 4  | 2014-05-26 | 2014-11-26 |
|   8   | Jonny   | Exam 1  | 2014-05-01 | 2017-05-01 |
+-------+---------+---------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: can you explain what is pe_d1 and pe_d2?

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) as well

Comment: RaghavPotluri, Both are dates, beginning one of the other end of a period =)

Comment: Strawberry, Sorry, did not know of this possibility, but now I will use the next ... thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first get the latest records from the patient_exams table and then join all the 3 tables with the filtered results, like this:

```
SELECT pe_id, pa_name, ex_name, pe_d1, pe_d2
FROM patient_exams pe
JOIN patient p
ON pe.pe_pa_id = p.pa_id
JOIN exams e
ON pe.pe_ex_id = e.ex_id
JOIN (
  SELECT pe_pa_id, pe_ex_id, MAX(pe_d2) AS max_pe_d2
  FROM patient_exams
  GROUP BY pe_pa_id, pe_ex_id
) AS t
ON pe.pe_pa_id = t.pe_pa_id 
AND pe.pe_ex_id = t.pe_ex_id 
AND pe.pe_d2 = t.max_pe_d2
ORDER BY pa_name, ex_name
```

### [Demo/Solution](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05909/15)

Thanks to everyone, works fine!

Comment: Hey, 

Thanks for the solution and to show a way to solve the problem... but i run SQL and i could identify an exception and the SQL above solve the problema, without a small detail, if the "patient_exams" is not repeat, however the real problema has this problem, more than one record for the same day and same type... 

how can I group again just for one type and for the same patient?

I put the problem in Fiddle: [New Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05909/1/0)

The record pe_id = 2 and 3 ( Are se same must be unique )
the same as:
The record pe_id = 8 and 4 ( Are se same must be unique )

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins among your tables,for the max exam date you need an additional self join to `patient_exams` with a subquery to get the maxima of exam date i.e `max(pe_d2)`

```
select 
pe.pe_id,
p.pa_name ,
e.ex_name ,
pe.pe_d1   ,
pe.pe_d2
from exams e
join patient_exams pe on(e.ex_id = pe.pe_ex_id)
join patient p on(p.pa_id= pe.pe_pa_id)
join (select `pe_pa_id`, `pe_ex_id` ,max(pe_d2) pe_d2 
      from patient_exams
     group by `pe_pa_id`, `pe_ex_id`) pee
on (pe.`pe_pa_id`= pee.`pe_pa_id` and
    pe.`pe_ex_id` = pee.`pe_ex_id` and
    pe.pe_d2 = pee.pe_d2
   )
order by p.pa_name  ,pee.pe_d2 desc
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad5e6/11)

Comment: Hey, 

Thanks for the solution and to show a way to solve the problem... but i run SQL and i could identify an exception and the SQL above solve the problema, without a small detail, if the "patient_exams" is not repeat, however the real problema has this problem, more than one record for the same day and same type... 

how can I group again just for one type and for the same patient?

I put the problem in Fiddle: [New Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05909/1/0)

The record pe_id = 2 and 3 ( Are se same must be unique )
the same as:
The record pe_id = 8 and 4 ( Are se same must be unique )

Comment: @lhpcsc this is a new question you should open a new question with all the details and brief regarding problem you have from the above comment it isn't clear to identify whats wrong in it and also once you have posted new question give me the link here and for above question choose the best answer you think and accept it for more see [*How does accepting an answer work?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)